# How do I fix Firestore not updating on my Phone (AndroidStudio apk deployment)

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, persistence, android-virtual-device

The error is:

`D/ShopsCollectionDisplaye: FromDBToShopsCollection: Doc{id=shop_test_Fb_1, shopImg=2131165326}
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.app.tacaalacaraman.wortheat, PID: 10527
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String (found in field 'shopImg')`

Cause now my app uses a string and so does my program, but my Android Device Does Not update the code or something like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally was cause Firestore was using db in cache(Persistance). So I had to disable Persistance with `FirebaseFirestoreSettings`:

```
private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
        .setPersistenceEnabled(false)
        .build();

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
    ....
```

Comment: This is not a really good long term solution because now your app will perform no document caching, which means it will be slower for your users and will cost you more money.  For development purposes, you should instead just uninstall or clear the data for the app to prevent old cached documents from being used,  When shipping new updates to your users, you should defend against these sort of problems in your code.